# Embedded Linux: setting the time without NTP

Tags: date, embedded

Working on a embedded Linux device built using yocto that is pulling a date via uart from another device with a satellite connection.  By the time we have access to this date, we are well into a fully initialized multi-threaded application as well as various daemons running etc.

From what I have read, using *stime()* or *settimeofday()* can result in breaking anything relying on timers.  I'm guessing that something like *std::this_thread::sleep_for()* would be included in this?

Is there a safe way to set the system time at this point or how do most embedded Linux devices that do not have internet access navigate this problem?

Edit: We do have an RTC but the implementation of hwclock we are using does not allow us to directly write to it, at least through the hwclock api.  Here is the *--help*:

```
BusyBox v1.24.1 (2018-11-14 12:40:41 PST) multi-call binary. 
Usage: hwclock [-r|--show] [-s|--hctosys] [-w|--systohc] [-t|--systz] [-l|--localtime] [-u|--utc] [-f|--rtc FILE]
```

And the [link](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/util-linux/hwclock.c?h=1_24_stable) to the hwclock source.

Comment: There is the RTC point of view, the system pov, and could even be the application pov....what do is necessary to do, what is needed and what exactly breaks? Could it pay out initializing the applications after getting the time if getting it on time is critical? What time resolution does the app need? And is there an RTC?

Comment: I used to have some apps running in an iOT, and they were quite happy even if the time via NTP got later in the game. Granted that after I bought an RTC for that, things were smoother, but it all depends on what you want to do and whether time is critical for the apllicational part.

Comment: There can be always the possibility of feeding an NTP daemon. As an example: http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/raspberry-pi3-gps-time.html

Comment: There is an rtc but our hwclock implementation doesn't have the ability to write directly to it -- only to and from the system time from what I can tell.  See my comment below on the usage options for our hwclock.

Comment: @jpsalm What is the use of writing directly to the RTC clock? It is only read at boot time. Nevertheless, it is not yet clear what you need to do and why.

Comment: We need to synchronize the system time with that of the satellite and as the rtc is powered by a large cap, when these devices are first powered on they will be out of date.  

We are pulling files down from the satellite based on date hence the need for synchronization, but it is not an essential operation so delaying until next boot (with direct rtc write) would be fine.  

The satellite time is only available to us well into the user application being started and thus am unsure if stime() or similar commands can be used safely.

Comment: Unfortunately its an external library supplied with sat module that is reading file creation dates and requesting new content as needed.  Spoofing those could work if possible but having an accurate system clock would be a nice to have for logging etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to write directly to the rtc using ioctrl.  Here's an implementation for anyone who comes across this:

```
#include <linux/rtc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>


int main(void)
{
  int fd;
  fd = open("/dev/rtc0",0);
  if (fd < 0)
    printf("Can't open rtc!");

  struct rtc_time time;

  time.tm_sec = 12;
  time.tm_min = 12;
  time.tm_hour = 7;
  time.tm_mday = 12;
  time.tm_mon = 7;
  time.tm_year = 118;

  if (ioctl(fd, RTC_SET_TIME, &time) < 0 )
    printf("Set rtc failed!");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't this exactly what the `"-w"` option to your `hwclock` does?

Comment: The -w option for BusyBox hwclock takes no arguments and simply writes the system clock into the rtc.  I needed the ability to load an arbitrary time into hwclock and then load that into the system on the next boot.

Comment: Usually, the `"-r"` option is run at boot time, and the `"-w"` option is run at shutdown (via init scripts). If your system is set up this way, you could just set the system time and reboot (bit of a sledge-hammer approach, I know - but would do the job)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `hwclock` which *should be* built into every embedded linux distro.

`$hwclock` is - as the command name suggest - a **hardware** clock, independent of the OS being used. These days it uses a low-power oscillator built into the motherboard,  that tracks the passage of time even when the machine is powered down (uses mb battery that will last a long time)

If `hwclock` is not available, there are other alternatives which I will gladly go over, but `hwclock` should be your goto command if available.

Comment: hwclock works in normal devices that have RTC - it writes and reads from it. There are iOT devices without an RTC.

Comment: I assume you are referring to the Raspberry Pi case, where a fairly advanced embedded device lacks a hardware clock capable of RTC. Raspberry Pi is a example of an outlier, because it tries to offer an enormous range of capabilities at as low of a price as possible, hence they chose to save money by forgoing a built-in battery powering one tiny IC capable of RTC.

Comment: The rpi suffers from it, but it is not alone, unfortunately.

Comment: Unfortunately the we are using the BusyBox 1.24.1 hwclock which as far as I can tell can only write to and from the system time.  Writing directly to hwclock would be ideal but doesn't seem to be available to me:


`BusyBox v1.24.1 (2018-11-14 12:40:41 PST) multi-call binary.

Usage: hwclock [-r|--show] [-s|--hctosys] [-w|--systohc] [-t|--systz] [-l|--localtime] [-u|--utc] [-f|--rtc FILE]`

Comment: [Here](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/util-linux/hwclock.c?h=1_24_stable) is the hwclock implementation.  I believe the -f option just allows us to point hwclock to a specific rtc.